# Do xampp really need visual c++ 2008?

Tags: xampp

I can't install Xampp v 1.8.1 as it requires Visual C++ 2008 but I have 2010 installed.

Answer (score 2):

It's not *Visual C++ 2008* (an integrated development environment), but *Visual C++ 2008 runtime* (a small package of libraries required to run Visual C++ 2008 apps). You can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582) and yes, its required, because different versions of runtimes aren't compatible with each other. Dont worry though, it won't take up much space or slow down your system.